# Common way of error-handling when using an external ruby-library

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling

i am creating a ruby-library (but in fact i am a java developer), that can be used by anyone If something goes wrong in a library what scenario would you prefer, that i raise an exception or that i just return error-codes.

In java it's pretty straight forward an exception, and you can define a "throws"-declaration, so that the user of the lib has to catch the exception.

What would be the preferable way in ruby?

regards && tia
  noircc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ruby, you `raise` an exception.  The exception can be a class, an instance of a class, or a class and a string, and normally the class is a decendent of [`StandardError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/StandardError.html), which is a decendent of [`Exception`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html).  To catch an exception, you do this:

```
begin
   raise StandardError, "weeee, exception!"
rescue StandardError => e # or => e for a general rescue
   puts "Exception Message: #{e.message}"
end
```

Normally, the exception handling would be done outside the library so you'd only have to worry about the `raise` line.  `throw` and `catch` still exist in ruby, but `raise` is the preferred method of exception handling.

Comment: So tell me if u use an external gem, and you call a function of the lib, would you prefer to get an exception or just an error-code (integer) to tell what went wrong.

Comment: @noircc The common behavior in ruby is to raise an exception.